# Git: A pull origin followed by a merge still not merging my branches

Tags: git, merge

I want to merge my `main-branch` into my `features-branch` (in other words, update the `features-branch`). I'm trying to do it like below:

```
$ git checkout features-branch
$ git pull origin main-branch
```

I get the message:

> Already up to date.

But the `features-branch` still has many files which were not updated, I can see it with:

```
git diff main-branch...features-branch
```

What's wrong with my `merge` process ? Why am I not being asked to resolve conflicts and merge ?

Comment: First thing, from above 3 commands 3rd one is unnecessary as you have already merged main-branch into feature-branch using 1st and 2nd command, the second thing is feature-branch is not merged into the main-branch i.e. changes in feature-branch are still not present in main-branch that's why you can see diff.

Comment: @AbhaySehgal Good point, indeed `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge`. I'll update my post.

Comment: The "already up to date" means that, according to the *commit graph*, the merge has already happened. (That you don't like the resulting *files* suggests that maybe, whoever did the merge, did it wrong, perhaps.) Just checking: you are aware that `main-branch...features-branch` finds the current merge base between those two commits, and diffs that merge base against the tip of `features-branch`?

Answer (score 1):

To merge your remote main-branch into your local features-branch what you are doing it's OK.

Take in consideration that your local main-branch is not going to be updated because the merge is done with your local features-branch.

Comment: I don't want to change the `main-branch` branch but just update the `features-branch`, so I can't run a `pull` (or `fetch`+`merge`) in the `main-branch`.